# Docker app supposed to output json to a dir on a volume, when running no data show

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I am working on a docker app. The purpose of this repo is to output some json into a volume. I am using a Dockerfile, docker-compose and a Makefile. I'll show the contents of each file below. Goal/desired outcome is that when I run using `make up` that the container runs and outputs the json.

Directory looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yaml
Dockerfile
Makefile
main/ # a directory
```

Here are the contents of directory Main:

```
example.R
```

Not sure the best order to show these files. Throughout my setup I refer to a variable $PROJECTS_DIR which is a global on the host / local:

```
echo $PROJECTS_DIR 
/home/doug/Projects
```

Here are my files:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  nextzen_ga_extract_marketing:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      start_date: "2020-11-18"
      start_date: "2020-11-19"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen/nextzen_google_analytics_extract_pipeline:/home/rstudio/Projects/nextzen_google_analytics_extract_pipeline
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
ADD main main
WORKDIR "/main"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    less \
    vim
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "example.R"]
```

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: build
build:
        docker-compose build

.PHONY: up
up:
        docker-compose pull
        docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: restart
restart:
        docker-compose restart

.PHONY: down
down:
        docker-compose down
```

Here is the contents of the 'main' file of the Docker app, example.R:

```
library(jsonlite)
unlink("../output_data", recursive = TRUE) # delete any existing data from previous runs
dir.create('../output_data')
write(toJSON(mtcars), '../output_data/ga_tables.json')
```

If I navigate into `${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen/nextzen_google_analytics_extract_pipeline/main` and then run `sudo Rscript example.R` then the file runs and outputs the json in `'../output_data/ga_tables.json` as expected.

I am struggling to get this to happen when running the container. If I navigate into `${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen/nextzen_google_analytics_extract_pipeline/` and then in the terminal run `make up` for:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

I then see:

```
make up
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "nextzengoogleanalyticsextractpipeline_default" with the default driver
Creating nextzengoogleanalyticsextractpipeline_nextzen_ga_extract_marketing_1 ... 
Creating nextzengoogleanalyticsextractpipeline_nextzen_ga_extract_marketing_1 .
```

It 'looks' like everything ran as expected with no errors. Except no output appears in directory output_data as expected?

I guess I'm misunderstanding or misusing `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "example.R"]`. My goal is that this file would run when the container is run.

How can I 'run' (if that's the correct terminology) my app so that it outputs json into /output_data/ga_tables.json?

Not sure what other info to provide? Any help much appreciated, I'm still getting to grips with docker.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your application from `/main` and its output is supposed to go into `../output_data` (so effectively `/output_data`), you need to bind mount this directory to have this output available on host. Therefore I would update your `docker-compose.yaml` to read something like this:

```
    volumes:
      - /path/to/output_data/on/host:/output_data
```

Bear in mind however that your script will not be able to remove `/output_data` when bind-mounted this way, so you might want to change your step to removing directory contents and not directory itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I did try this but got the same result. The existing volume should in theory cover your suggestion since ` ${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen/nextzen_google_analytics_extract_pipeline:` is the volume and I was creating a dir nested underneath that volume from within the container. Nevertheless I did try adding that explicit path. When I run `make build` and then `make up` the terminal is bust for ~2-3 seconds. There's no error message or way for me to see if it ran the scripts `make up
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "nextzengoogleanalyticsextractp...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this working when I used full paths as opposed to relative paths.